# Is it possible to rearrange the items in qgis layer context menu?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I'm referring to the menu I get when I right-click on a layer in the TOC. I'd like to move Properties to the top. I can't find anything in the customization dialog that seems to apply.

Comment: If you are looking for quick access to the Properties dialog, you can define legend layer's double-click action to open it. Look in Options->Canvas-n-Legend. The double-click can be defined to open Properties or the layer's Attribute Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found how to re-arrange those items, but most of the items in that list can be assigned a shortcut key through *Settings* -> *Configure shortcuts...* as an interim option:

[image: setting shortcut keys in QGIS]

You could make a feature request for the ability to re-arrange context menus at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: It can't be rearranged because it is created on the fly in the legend class.  I had a look if there was a way to do it from Python but due to the on the fly nature it can't really happen.